# Incompatible block pointer types - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, return, nsarray, nsurlconnection

I have an iOS app with a function which is in charge of making an asynchronous network request. The request itself works just fine, but the problem I am having is with the function `return` statement which is causing errors.

Here is my function:

```
-(NSArray *)get_data:(NSString *)size {

    // Set up the data request.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com/info.json"]];
    NSURLRequest *url_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // Begin the asynchronous data loading.
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:url_request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if (error == nil) {

            // Convert the response JSON data to a dictionary object.
            NSError *my_error = nil;
            NSDictionary *feed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&my_error];

            if (feed != nil) {

                // Store the returned data in the data array.
                NSArray *topping_data;

                for (int loop = 0; loop < [[feed objectForKey:@"toppings_data"] count]; loop++) {

                    NSString *size_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[feed objectForKey:@"toppings_data"] objectAtIndex:loop] valueForKey:@"Size"]];

                    if ([size_name isEqualToString:size]) {
                        topping_data = [[feed objectForKey:@"toppings_data"] objectAtIndex:loop];
                    }
                }

                return topping_data;
            }

            else {
                return @[@"no data"];
            }
        }

        else {
            return @[@"no data"];
        }
    }];
}
```

I am getting the following error message on the line of code `[NSURLConnection sendAsync....`:

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSArray *(^)(NSURLResponse
>   *__strong, NSData *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(NSURLResponse * _Nullable __strong, NSData *
>   _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)'

What am I doing wrong here?

All I am trying to avoid, is the function returning BEFORE the asynchronous request has completed. Otherwise the function will not return any data, which is not what I want.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

best way to return data in async block is make a block callback as argument of function and callback return value here:

```
- (void)get_data:(NSString *)size completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *array))completionHandler {
    // ...
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:url_request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        // ...
        completionHandler(array);
        // ...
    }];
}
```

use :

```
    [self get_data:someString completionHandler:^(NSArray *array) {
       // process array here
    }];
```

Comment: So the completion handler of the async block is returning data but the function itself doesn't do anything cool.

Comment: What's the advantage of adding another completion block?

Comment: @trojanfoe it's simple to use and be used any where in cocoa interface :)

Comment: It appears to add complexity.  You decode the network data to an array in the first block and then pass it to the second block for storage/further processing.  That just adds complexity and it doesn't answer the question, which is about a compiler error message.

Comment: @trojanfoe I just think he want to return something and process it. So it's one way. Yes we can process result direct inside block but it's make code not clearly with a long function

Comment: But you don't answer the question.  You are reacting to comments made by the OP to my answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't want to argue about my answer can resolve this question or not. YES it's may not true answer. But I think my snippet will help he in other ways

Comment: @Supertecnoboff NSURLConnection is going to deprecated. I think you should change to use NSURLSession

Comment: @ABáo I can do that. But can that be used like this with a completion handler, maybe you could share an example?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff have a lot of document about NSURLSession. You better to learn about using it your self. about how to use completion block in NSURLSession it will the same when using NSURLConnection

Answer (score 2):

The block returns nothing:

```
void ^(NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *)
```

So you cannot return things:

```
return @[@"no data"];
```

The code that calls the block is not interested in what it returns; if you want to store state then add an instance variable or call a method.

Comment: I think I sort of understand what you are saying, but the asynchronous request block is inside a function of type ```NSArray```, and that function does return an array. I just want that function to return what ever the block downloads from the request.

Comment: The alternative is that I could use a Synchronous request instead which doesn't even have a code block.

Comment: The networking code that actually calls the block does not care what the block returns as the block is intended for you to process and squirrel-away the data in whatever way you like.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:url_request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

to

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:url_request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *_Nullable response, NSData *_Nullable data, NSError *_Nullable error)
```